# Update no Banco de dados pelo c#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Estou tentando fazer um update em meu banco de dados pelo visual Studio(c#), porém o update não está sendo realizado não sei porque.

***Script da tabela***(`sql developer`):

```
CREATE TABLE Login
(
  Cod_login NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
  Usuario VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
  Senha VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
  cod_Nivel number(5)NOT NULL,
  Status_Login CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT PK_Cod_login_Login PRIMARY KEY (Cod_login)
);
```

script do update do c#:

```
public void AlterarSenha(string usuario)
{
    string strQuery;
    strQuery = (" UPDATE Login ");
    strQuery += (" SET ");
    strQuery += ("senha = '" + _senha + "' ");
    strQuery += (", Status_Login ='" + 1 + "'");
    strQuery += (" WHERE ");
    strQuery += (" usuario = '" + _usuario + "' ");
    clnBancoDados ObjClnBancoDados = new clnBancoDados();
    ObjClnBancoDados.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
}

public void Alterar()
{
    if (txtnovasenha.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Digite Sua Nova Senha!");
    }
    if ((txtnovasenha.Text.Length < 4))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A Senha Deve Conter no Mínimo 4 Digitos!");
    }
    if ((txtnovasenha.Text.Length > 8))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A Senha Deve Conter no Máximo 8 Digitos!");
    }
    else
    {
        clnlogin login = new clnlogin();
        login.Senha = txtnovasenha.Text;
        login.AlterarSenha(txtLogin.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("A Senha do Usuário " 
           + txtLogin.Text + " foi Alterada com Sucesso para " 
           + login.Senha + "!",
           "Alteração", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Ele mostra a mensagem, porém não realiza o update. Já tentei mudar várias coisas mas não consegui. Eu fiz algo de errado?

Comment: Este código está incompleto, né?

Comment: Não.Só faltou o botão salvar, cujo só chama o método Alterar();

Comment: E aquela chave faltando no primeiro método?

Comment: arrumei. vacilo meu.

Comment: `strQuery += (", Status_Login ='" + 1 + "'");` tenta mudar aqui: `strQuery += (", Status_Login ='" + 1.ToString() + "' ");`

Comment: tentei, não adiantou.

Comment: Que componente é esse `clnBancoDados` ?

Comment: É onde eu faço a conexão com o meu banco.

Comment: Precisamos do conteúdo do método ExecutaComando() para poder lhe repassar uma resposta, provavelmente ele é a origem do problema.

Comment: Uma observação: você está indo pela pior maneira para gravar um registro em C#. Use o `SqlCommand` com `paramentros` e tenha um código simples e fácil de dar manutenção. Links que podem te ajudar https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx e http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-parametros-no-sqlcommand-em-c/28440

Comment: Coloca a parte do código do método: ObjClnBancoDados.ExecutaComando(strQuery); para ver como está fazendo. pode ser que esteja faltando um ExecureNonQuery() ou um Savechanges, dependendo da sua abordagem...

Comment: Posso até colocar, mas acho que não é isso, pois as outras funções estão funcionando.

Comment: se eu comentar as linhas://strQuery += (" WHERE ");
            //strQuery += (" usuario = '" + _usuario + "' "); ele funciona; porém em vez de atualizar só uma linha da minha tabela, ele atualiza todas.

Comment: O usuário que vc está tentando atualizar existe na tabela? só pode ser isso então

Comment: Sim, existe. Deve ser alguma coisa boba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se atente aos parâmetros que você esta passando para seu método.

Uma boa verificação é você fazer o `select` direto no banco de dados para ver se os dados realmente existem.

`select * from Login WHERE usuario =` igual ao valor do seu `txtLogin.Text`...

Outra coisa, o seu `WHERE usuario =` é = `txtLogin.Text` veja o campo `usuario = Login`, um pouco estranho a nomenclatura entre a aplicação e o banco de dados.

Outra coisa curiosa esta no seu método abaixo.

```
public void AlterarSenha(string usuario)
{
    string strQuery;
    strQuery = (" UPDATE Login ");
    strQuery += (" SET ");
    strQuery += ("senha = '" + _senha + "' ");
    strQuery += (", Status_Login ='" + 1 + "'");
    strQuery += (" WHERE ");
    strQuery += (" usuario = '" + _usuario + "' ");
    clnBancoDados ObjClnBancoDados = new clnBancoDados();
    ObjClnBancoDados.ExecutaComando(strQuery);
}
```

Veja o seu parâmetro `AlterarSenha(string usuario)` ..... **usuario** e veja o que você esta usando no trecho `strQuery += (" usuario = '" + _usuario + "' ");` aqui seu parametros tem um **_** no **_usuario** , ou seja, não é o mesmo parâmetro recebido no seu método.

Para completar, o ideal é que seu método `AlterarSenha` retornasse um booleano informando se realmente foi feito a transação no banco.

Ainda sim, espero que isso seja apenas um treinamento ou trabalho de curso, pois essa forma de passar parâmetros não é nada boa, isso deixa a aplicação vulnerável a [sql injection](http://gizmodo.com/5498412/sql-injection-license-plate-hopes-to-foil-euro-traffic-cameras) ops, é esse o [link certo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Comment: Era o meu parâmetro que estava errado.